# Probability of winning a dice game involving a minimum number of specific rolls

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in a dice rolling problem (of my own design, i.e. there may be no simple answer) where a player rolls a six-sided die until a $1$ is observed (and the player loses), or at least five $6$'s and at least one $5$ is observed at which point the game ends (and the player wins). What is the probability the player wins?

If we simplify the game to end as a win when the player rolls at least five 6's, the calculation is simple. Suppose the player repeatedly rolls a die until a 6 or a 1 is observed then stops. Then $$\mathbb{P}(\text{A six is observed}) = 1/2$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(\text{A one is observed}) = 1/2,$$ so $$\mathbb{P}(\text{The player wins}) = 1/2^5.$$

Returning to the original problem, is there an easy way to insert the condition that at least one $5$ is observed? Using the same observation in the previous paragraph, the probability of rolling a $5$ before a $1$ on repeated die rolls is $1/2$ and so I believe a lower bound on the probability is $1/64$. But I am having trouble unraveling things from here.

I've tried defining $A$ to be the event of rolling five $6$'s before a $1$ and $B$ to be the event of rolling a $5$ before rolling a $1$ and then writing $$\mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$$

But the problem remains to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A|B).$ I've then tried to break up $B$ into infinitely many disjoint events $B_{i}$, where $B_{i}$ is the event that the $i$th roll of the die results in the first $5$ before a $1$ to hopefully reduce this problem to calculating $\sum_{i} \mathbb{P}(A|B_{i})$. However, after calculating $\mathbb{P}(A|B_{1})$ things seem to get out of hand for me:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|B_{1}) = 1/2^5$$

\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(A|B_{2}) &= \mathbb{P}(A| B_{2} \cap \text{first roll is a six}) + \mathbb{P}(A | B_{2} \cap \text{first roll is not a six})\\
&= (1/6)(1/2^4) + (4/6)(1/2^5)\\
\mathbb{P}(A|B_{3}) &= \mathbb{P}(A| B_{3} \cap \text{first two rolls are a six}) + \mathbb{P}(A| B_{3} \cap \text{one of the first two rolls are a six}) + \mathbb{P}(A| B_{3} \cap \text{none of the two rolls are a six})\\
&= {2\choose 2} (1/6^2) (4/6)^{0}(1/2^{5-2}) + {2\choose 1}(1/6)(4/6)(1/2^{5-1}) + {2\choose 0}(1/6^0)(4/6)^{2}(1/2^{5-0})
\end{align*}

At this point, I suppose I can continue writing down this pattern since taking the first term of $\mathbb{P}(A|B_{2})$ and the second term of $\mathbb{P}(A|B_{3})$ it looks like I get an infinite sum

$$(1/6)(1/2^4)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n\choose 1}(4/6)^{n-1} = 3/32$$

but to be honest, I don't even know how to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (4/6)^{n-1}=9$ without a CAS for support. It seems like at this point I need to calculate infinitely many sums of the form

$$(1/6^{k})(1/2^{\max(5-k,0)})\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} {n\choose k}(4/6)^{n-k},\, k = 0,1,2,\ldots$$

and I've about as far into a brick wall as I can get trying to solve this problem. I can't tell if somewhere several paragraphs ago, there was a clever use of symmetry, an error in counting, a common indentity in probability theory, a smarter choice of $A$ and $B$, or an embarrassing elementary mistake that should have made this problem easy or if this is a difficult problem to reach an exact solution.

Comment: Do you know about Markov chains?

Comment: @saulspatz I know a little bit, but it's not clear how I would use them in this context. I can see how losing can be an absorbing state, but it's not immediately obvious to me how I can encode the "at least five $6$'s and a $5$" part of the problem into a matrix so I can reduce this to an eigenvector problem.

Comment: @saulspatz After working on it a bit more, I think I have a satisfactory answer following your hint using 12 states but it'd take me some time to actually write down the entire matrix and find the stationary values to ensure the numbers look sensible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reflection, I don't think the Markov chain machinery is necessary for this problem.  If we win we roll $k$ sixes then a $5$, then $5-k$ sixes, without any $1$ appearing, where $0\leq k\leq5.$  Before the $5$ appears, there are $3$ rolls of interest: $1,5,6$  After the $5$ appears only $1$ and $6$ are of interest.  After $5$ sixes have appeared, with no $5$, only $1$ and $5$ matter.

This gives a probability of winning of $$\sum_{k=0}^4\left(\frac13\right)^{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)^{5-k}+\left(\frac13\right)^5\cdot\frac12$$

The sum represents the cases where we roll $k<5$ sixes before rolling the $5$.  The last term come from the case where we roll all $5$ sixes before the $5$.